# Identifying a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, information-theory

This is a very basic question in the theory of Markov chains and I'm just not sure how to prove it mathematically.

Say we have random variables $X, Y$ that are correlated and we have a possibly random function of the random variable $Y$ denoted $g(Y)=\hat{X}$. Is it obvious that $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow \hat{X}$? How does one give a sound proof of this?

This is from Tom Cover's "Elements of Information Theory", where Fano's inequality gets proven.

Comment: Indeed if $\hat X$ is a function of $Y$ then $\hat X$ and any random variable are independent conditionally on $Y$, in particular, $X\to Y\to\hat X$ is a Markov chain (if this is what you are asking).

Comment: @Did Regarding what you just posted, we then have to show that $p(x, \hat{x} \mid y)=p(x\mid y)p(\hat{x}\mid y)$? I guess I know how to prove Markov iff conditionally independent. So then my trouble is proving that conditional independence holds here.

Comment: But this is obvious since, conditionally on $Y$, $\hat X$ is *deterministic*, hence independent of anything.

Comment: Hmmm. I know this is very basic (and may be annoying) but could you please elaborate as why $\hat{X}$ would be independent of anything given $Y$? Also would I have to worry about the possibly random function $g$?

Comment: By elaborate I meant show mathematically.